# php how can I merge two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, merge, key

i am trying to merge two similar arrays with the same keys

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4064628
    [1] => 4064953
    [2] => 4064922
    [3] => 4064870
    [4] => 4064789
    [5] => 4064631
    [6] => 4065044
    [7] => 4064942
    [8] => 4064938
    [9] => 4064936
)
Array
(
    [0] => 165020
    [1] => 165026
    [2] => 165025
    [3] => 165023
    [4] => 165024
    [5] => 165021
    [6] => 165027
    [7] => 165043
    [8] => 165042
    [9] => 165045
)
```

but when i use *array_merge* or *array_merge_recursive* gives the same output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4064628
    [1] => 4064953
    [2] => 4064922
    [3] => 4064870
    [4] => 4064789
    [5] => 4064631
    [6] => 4065044
    [7] => 4064942
    [8] => 4064938
    [9] => 4064936
    [10] => 165020
    [11] => 165026
    [12] => 165025
    [13] => 165023
    [14] => 165024
    [15] => 165021
    [16] => 165027
    [17] => 165043
    [18] => 165042
    [19] => 165045
)
```

but i try to get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4064628
            [1] => 165020
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4064935
            [1] => 165026
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4064922
            [1] => 165025
        )
     .......
```

can someone help please to merge these two arrays?
this seems so simple but there is something i don't get, and i don't know what

Comment: `$zipped = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);`

Comment: nope, i submited the solution from Noe CB, it worked for me

Comment: You are asking for "array transposition" -- this has been been asked roughly 100 times on Stack Overflow.  Commonly devs are passing in one array that needs to be "spread".  In your case, you just pass the two arrays in individually. https://3v4l.org/QKLLg

Comment: @billyonecan please help to close questions when you know that they are duplicates.  By not closing, you allowed new users to waste their time providing redundant content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output_arr=[];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
$output_arr[]=[$value,$array2[$key]];}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=[];
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
    array_push($arr, [$arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]]);
}
```